# Find a polynomial $P(x)$ that is a multiple of $(x-4)$ and when divided by $(x-3)$ the remainder is 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

So I'm at a loss I'm not sure what to do.

1. I know that if it is a multiple of $(x-4)$ then one of it's roots is 4
2. I also know that evaluating the $P(3)=2$

I'm thinking of making a system of equations but don't really know how. A hint would be really cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

There are tons of options.  Let $P(x) = (x-4)(x-a)$ and by using $P(3)=2$, solve for $a$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $P(X)=(X-4)Q(X)$.

Then $P(3)=2$ if and only if $Q(3)=-2$. Can you find any such $Q$?

Answer (score 0):

So we need $P(4) = 0$ and $P(3)=2$.

If $P = ax +b$ then $4a + b= 0$ and $3a + b=2$.  So $a= -2$ and $b=8$.

So $P(x) = -2x + 8 = -2(x-4)= -2(x-3) +2$ is the lowest power such poly.

If you want a higher power just solve $\sum q_k 4^k = 0$ while $\sum r_k 3^k = 2$.

=====

$P(x) = Q(x)(x-4)$

And $P(x) = R(x)(x-3) + 2$

Let $Q(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n q_k x^k$ and $R(x) =\sum_{k=0}^m r_kx^k$ so

$P(x) = Q(x)(x-4) = R(x)(x-3) + 2$

$\sum_{k=0}^n q_k x^{k+1} - \sum_{k=0}^n 4q_k x^k = \sum_{k=0}^m r_kx^{k+1} - \sum_{k=0}^m 3r_kx^k + 2$

$q_n x^{n+1} +\sum_{k=1}^{n}[q_{k-1} - 4q_k]x^k -4 q_0 = r_m x^{n+1} +\sum_{k=1}^{m}[r_{k-1} - 3r_k]x^k -3 r_0 + 2$.

So

1)  $m = n$

2) $-4q_0 = -3r_0 + 2$

3) $q_{k-1}-4q_k = r_{k-1}- 3r_k$ for all $1 \le k \le n-1$

4) $q_n = r_n$

Any solution to the four above will do.

We can set $r_0 = 2$ are $q_0 =1$ just to make things easy.

Then $1-4q_1 = 2-3r_1$.  And we can, to keep things short, let $r_1=q_1$ and solve:  $q_1=r_1 =-1$ and let $n=1$.

So $Q(x) = -x+1$ and $R(x) = -x+2$ and $(-x+1)(x-4) = (-x+2)(x-3) + 2 = -x^2 +5x-4=P(x)$ is one solution.

But there are infinitely more.